# I can't generate a prod version in Ionic (AoT Failed)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, angular2-aot

Recently I updated my ionic app version to latest. Actually, I used the same dependencies versions for angular packages from the super template of Ionic, because I always have problems with dependencies when I try to upgrade Ionic.

When I run these commands everything is okey:

```
ionic serve --watch

ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --livereload --device

ionic cordova build android --dev
```

But if I run:
`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

I get this error:

[image]

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "ionic-hello-world",
"author": "Ionic Framework",
"homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ionic:copy": "ionic-app-scripts copy"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/app-minimize": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/screenshot": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "angular2-uuid": "git+https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-uuid.git",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
    "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": "git+https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot.git",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.11.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-event": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-appminimize": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.10.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-http": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.2",
    "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "^0.8.5",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
    "nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio": "git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-backgroundaudio.git",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
    "propagating-hammerjs": "^1.4.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "soundcloud": "^3.3.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "Mindfulness: An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "browser",
        "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-file": {},
        "cordova-plugin-http": {},
        "cordova-plugin-media": {
            "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
        },
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
        "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {},
        "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
            "APP_ID": "my app id",
            "APP_NAME": "Pausa by AnimaEdu"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-inapppurchase": {},
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": {},
        "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {},
        "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-appminimize": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "nl.x-services.plugins.backgroundaudio": {}
    }
}
```

}

Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
/**
 * Native providers
 */
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import {Insomnia} from '@ionic-native/insomnia';
import {LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {DatePicker} from '@ionic-native/date-picker';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';
import {InAppPurchase} from "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase"
import {SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import {Media} from '@ionic-native/media';
import {Keyboard} from "@ionic-native/keyboard";
import {AppMinimize} from "@ionic-native/app-minimize";
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

/**
 * Components
 */
import {MyApp} from './app.component';
import {BottomMenuComponent} from '../components/bottom-menu/bottom-menu';
import {AudioListComponent} from '../components/audio-list/audio-list';

/**
 * Pages
 */
import {HomePage} from '../pages/home/home';
import {LoginPage} from '../pages/login/login';
import {StartPage} from '../pages/start/start';
import {RegisterPage} from '../pages/register/register';
import {SubscriptionPage} from '../pages/subscription/subscription';
import {PractisesPage} from '../pages/practises/practises';
import {ReminderPage} from '../pages/reminder/reminder';
import {AboutPage} from '../pages/about/about';
import {CreateAccountPage} from '../pages/create-account/create-account';
import {LoginOptionsPage} from '../pages/login-options/login-options';
import {PlayerPage} from '../pages/player/player';
import {ProfilePage} from '../pages/profile/profile';
import {TimerPage} from '../pages/timer/timer';
import {CreateIntermediateBreatheSoundPage} from '../pages/create-intermediate-breathe-sound/create-intermediate-breathe-sound';
import {RememberPage} from '../pages/remember/remember';
import {PractiseAudiosPage} from '../pages/practise-audios/practise-audios';
import {HowtoPage} from '../pages/howto/howto';
import {PlayerOfflinePage} from '../pages/player-offline/player-offline';
import {PrivacyPage} from '../pages/privacy/privacy';
import {TermsPage} from '../pages/terms/terms';
import {DownloadsPage} from '../pages/downloads/downloads';
import {BeginnerTrackPage} from '../pages/beginner-track/beginner-track';
import {FAQPage} from '../pages/faq/faq';
import {WeekDaysModalPage} from "../components/week-days-modal/week-days-modal";
import {TimerCompletionModalPage} from "../pages/timer-completion-modal/timer-completion-modal";
import {WelcomePage} from "../pages/welcome/welcome";
import {WalkthroughPage} from "../pages/walkthrough/walkthrough";
import {SubscriptionInfoPage} from "../pages/subscription-info/subscription-info";

/**
 * Custom providers
 */
import {FacebookEvents} from '../providers/facebook-events';
import {CredentialsStorage} from '../providers/credentials-storage';
import {ToastNotifications} from '../providers/toast-notifications';
import {NetworkManager} from '../providers/network-manager';
import {TimeFormatter} from '../providers/time-formatter';
import {FirebaseCustomProvider} from '../providers/firebase-custom/firebase-custom';
import {LocalNotificationsProvider} from '../providers/local-notifications-provider';
import {TimerOptionsProvider} from '../providers/timer-options-provider';
import {DynamicStyles} from '../providers/dynamic-styles';
import {BottomMenuItemProvider} from '../providers/bottom-menu-item';
import {SideMenuProvider} from '../providers/sidemenu-provider';
import {ReminderProvider} from '../providers/reminder';
import {AlertsProvider} from '../providers/alerts';
import {IdGeneratorService} from '../providers/id-generator';
import {AudioProvider} from '../providers/audio';
import {DaysProvider} from '../providers/days';
import {MeditationsProvider} from "../providers/meditations";
import {SubscriptionProvider} from "../providers/subscription-provider";
import {TimerProvider} from '../providers/timer';
import {AuthProvider} from '../providers/auth-provider';
import {HomeProvider} from '../providers/home';
import {PractiseProvider} from '../providers/practise-provider';
import {DailySentenceProvider} from '../providers/daily-sentence-provider';
import {OfflinePhrase} from '../providers/offline-phrase';
import {FirebaseAuthProvider} from '../providers/firebase-custom/firebase-auth';
import {RememberProvider} from '../providers/remember';
import { BeginnerTrackWeekProvider } from '../providers/beginner-track-week';

/**
 * Repositories
 */
import {ReminderRepository} from '../repositories/reminder';
import {AudioRepository} from '../repositories/audio';
import {DaysRepository} from '../repositories/day';
import {TimerConfigRepository} from '../repositories/timer-config';
import {SubscriptionRepository} from '../repositories/subscription';
import {BeginnerTrackWeekRepository} from '../repositories/beginner-track-week';
import {MeditationsRepository} from "../repositories/meditations";
import {WalkthroughStepsRepository} from "../repositories/walkthrough-steps";

/**
 * Charts
 */
import {ChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts/charts/charts';
import '../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js';


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/lang/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        LoginPage,
        StartPage,
        RegisterPage,
        SubscriptionPage,
        PractisesPage,
        ReminderPage,
        AboutPage,
        CreateAccountPage,
        LoginOptionsPage,
        PlayerPage,
        ProfilePage,
        TimerPage,
        CreateIntermediateBreatheSoundPage,
        RememberPage,
        PractiseAudiosPage,
        BottomMenuComponent,
        PlayerOfflinePage,
        HowtoPage,
        PrivacyPage,
        TermsPage,
        DownloadsPage,
        AudioListComponent,
        BeginnerTrackPage,
        WeekDaysModalPage,
        WelcomePage,
        WalkthroughPage,
        FAQPage,
        TimerCompletionModalPage,
        SubscriptionInfoPage
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
            activator: 'highlight',
            modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
            modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
            menuType: 'overlay',
            swipeBackEnabled: true,
            scrollAssist: false,
            autoFocusAssist: false
        }),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(
            {
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            }),
        ChartsModule,
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        LoginPage,
        StartPage,
        RegisterPage,
        SubscriptionPage,
        PractisesPage,
        ReminderPage,
        AboutPage,
        CreateAccountPage,
        LoginOptionsPage,
        PlayerPage,
        ProfilePage,
        TimerPage,
        CreateIntermediateBreatheSoundPage,
        RememberPage,
        PractiseAudiosPage,
        PlayerOfflinePage,
        HowtoPage,
        PrivacyPage,
        TermsPage,
        DownloadsPage,
        BeginnerTrackPage,
        WeekDaysModalPage,
        WelcomePage,
        WalkthroughPage,
        FAQPage,
        TimerCompletionModalPage,
        SubscriptionInfoPage
    ],
    providers: [
        Storage,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: IonicErrorHandler
        },
        FacebookEvents,
        ToastNotifications,
        CredentialsStorage,
        NetworkManager,
        Insomnia,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        Facebook,
        LocalNotifications,
        TimeFormatter,
        FirebaseCustomProvider,
        LocalNotificationsProvider,
        TimerOptionsProvider,
        DynamicStyles,
        BottomMenuItemProvider,
        SideMenuProvider,
        DatePicker,
        ReminderProvider,
        ReminderRepository,
        AlertsProvider,
        IdGeneratorService,
        AudioRepository,
        AudioProvider,
        File,
        InAppPurchase,
        DaysProvider,
        DaysRepository,
        MeditationsProvider,
        MeditationsRepository,
        SubscriptionProvider,
        TimerConfigRepository,
        TimerProvider,
        AuthProvider,
        HomeProvider,
        PractiseProvider,
        DailySentenceProvider,
        OfflinePhrase,
        SocialSharing,
        SubscriptionRepository,
        FirebaseAuthProvider,
        RememberProvider,
        Media,
        Keyboard,
        BeginnerTrackWeekProvider,
        BeginnerTrackWeekRepository,
        AppMinimize,
        WalkthroughStepsRepository,
        HTTP
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Extra info:
- I don't have lazy loading. (I don't have @IonicPage decorator and `.module.ts` files in components).

Maybe a wrong version of `app-scripts`?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Every **provider** is listed in `providers:[...]` except `TranslateLoader`. But I don't know `TranslateModule` well, so I cannot be sure that `TranslateModule.forRoot` usage is valid or not without registering the provider.

Comment: I fixed that error with this solution: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/885
But now I have another error: `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`  So i'm researching for that.

Comment: @HyuckKang I tried including `TranslateModule` in providers, but I still having the last error I mentioned in the comment above :/

Comment: Maybe `node --max-old-space-size=4096 ${PATH}/ionic cordova build android --prod` can help you

Comment: Doing that I have:
`rror: Cannot find module '/home/ivan/bin:/home/ivan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin:/home/ivan/Android/platform-tools:/home/ivan/Android/tools/ionic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:507:3`

Comment: What exact command did you input? and where is you global `ionic`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay but, I found the solution and I was testing if the problem was absolutely fixed. I had `"firebase": "^5.1.0"` and it was solved downgrading it to `"firebase": "^4.12.1"`. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Heres is the font: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1036 . The user MichaelHuy commented that